# Is it possible to make an input="text" to require either an email or a tel?

Tags: javascript, html

I made an `<input type="text" placeholder="phone or email" required="required" />` and I was just wondering if I can make it so that it would require either a valid email or a number?

Comment: HTML5 does have type="tel" and also type="email", but in order to determine if one should be used over the other you're going to need some javascript doing the heavy lifting. Watching for an @ sign or something would probably be the easiest way to go and then validate based on that.

Comment: @ThatTechGuy Im trying to do something of a tel and email combination, where if its not an email, then it should be a tel, without having to rely on js.

Comment: Yeah, DRDs answer is pretty much your only option, I wasn't aware of a regex attribute but since it's so new as DRD explained you'll have issues with a few browsers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to implement HTML-only data validation on `input`s using `pattern` attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/887saeeg/.  Coupled with `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo-classes, it is possible to have a decent error-checking functionality using only presentation technologies.  Of course, a modern browser is required.  (I cover browser-only validation in more detail in the last volume of my Functional CSS book series [available on Amazon]).

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type = "text" placeholder = "Phone or Email" required pattern = "^([a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3})|(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})$"/>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Send" />
</form>
```

EDIT: Example using CSS pseudo-classes: http://jsfiddle.net/292pp5gk/.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <label>
        <input type = "text" placeholder = "Phone or Email" required pattern = "^([a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3})|(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})$"/>
        <span class = "error">Please provide a valid telephone or email</span>
    </label>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Send" />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    position: relative;
}

.error {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
    display: none;
    background-color: hsla(0, 50%, 70%, 1);
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font: normal 12px/1 Sans-Serif;
}

.error:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent hsla(0, 50%, 70%, 1) transparent;
    border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    left: 15px;
    top: -5px;
}

input {
    outline: 0;
}

input:invalid + .error {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: For some reason, it still doesnt work for phone numbers, tried to tweak the regex but im not too good with it...

Comment: I am using US format of XXX-XXX-XXXX.  So a phone number of 202-343-2343 works in both latest Chrome and Firefox.  For other phone number formats you'll need to change the RegExp.

Comment: Input type value exist for a reason. And many devices refer to these values when displaying a keyboard. By keeping the type="text" when you're asking for an e-mail, everything should work fine, but devices like the iPhone may not render the custom keyboard they provide for type="email".

Comment: @mbnyc It's a form that I'd remove on mobiles and tablet layout anyway so I should be fine for now.

Comment: But how to store it in different rows/database locations based on if it is a contact or an email

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using form validator and i was able to solve my problem with
`Validators.pattern(new RegExp("([0-9 ]{11})|([a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3})"))`

`([0-9 ]{11})` check for 11 digits number

`|` Or

`([a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3})` check for valid email